# When to use nested resources in a RESTful API

Tags: api, rest, api-design

I have two resources: users and links.

Users can have several links associated with them. I have designed my RESTful API so that you can reach the links associated with a user at the following URI:

`/users/:id/links`

However, I always need to have a URI for just links – sometimes I might want all links, regardless of user.

For this I have:

`/links`

Does this sound okay? Having two URIs for links?

I wonder if I should instead reach the links for a user with a URI such as:

`/links/user/:id` or `/links/?user=:id`

This way, I only have one resource for links.

Comment: hmm.. This one seems more elegant: `/links/user/:id`

Comment: @theMarceloR: That's the only example out of the three that I *don't* find particularly clear. Is the resource for a link or a user? The URI is far less ambiguous using either the nested resource method (`/users/:id/links`) or the query string method (`/links/?user=:id`) since it is in fact a query. `/links/user/:id` might look nice and/or be easier to route in some frameworks but it is actually quite confusing.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

No, there is nothing wrong with having multiple resources for the same "thing", in this case lists of links.

We were recently struggling with the same problem. Our decision was to have all resources where there is not a *strict* ownership not to be nested. In other words, the links would be modeled under

```
/links -- all links
/links/:linkid -- a particular link
```

Then, filters on the links collection are expressed as query parameters. So to get the links of a certain user, you would use:

```
/links?user=/users/:userid
```

This also allows for easier composition of filters:

```
/links?user=/users/10&since=2013-01-01
```

And it is easy to understand conceptually - you have a collection of items, and you add filters to it.

That being said, there is nothing more "RESTful" about this approach than any other URI naming scheme. It's just a convention we found human-readable and easy for us developers to understand and embrace. REST doesn't care about what you put in your resource identifiers.

Comment: "All resources where there is not a strict ownership not to be nested" sounds like a good rule to have. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: I'd say that there *is* something wrong with having multiple resources for the same physical entity, but that's not actually what this is. Each individual link has a canonical URL (links/:id), whereas each of the resources above are in fact a single resource (/links) with filters applied. Also, I'm weirded out by the `?user=users/:userid` in the query string; what is wrong with just `?userid=:userid`?

Comment: @Aaronaught: the reason to stick to uri's instead of bare ids is so that clients can treat all resource identifiers equally, that is a client need only know that 'this user is identified by `"/*******"`; where the `*`'s are opaque.  but that same identifier can always be used to refer to that resource (as in, with links), to fetch the most current version of that resource, and so on.  the content of that uri is only understood by the origin server.  This also means that if the identifiers need to change, say `/realm/:businessid/users/:id`, the client doens't change at all.

Comment: @TokenMacGuy: Sorry, I don't understand any part of your comment. What's the practical difference between `/users/:userid/links` and `/links?userid=:userid`? In both cases the identifiers don't change, they fetch the current version of that resource, and the client treats them the same way. There's no such thing as a canonical URL for this because it's not a resource, it's a query, so these are just two different types of query syntax. I'm also not clear on how the client wouldn't need to change if the URL structure changes; that's considered a breaking change in REST unless a 301 is in place.

Comment: @Aaronaught: I might have misunderstood your concern.  Supposing `/links` supports a query interface, `/links?user=/users/123` permits a black-box approach to resource identifiers in clients that `/links?userid=123` does not.  the latter requires the client understand what a userid is and how to get it, presumably out of the resource it obtained from `/users/123` or `/links/456/user`.  The former means the client can use the uri unmodified; supposing the `/links/.../user` gives a hypermedia response (say, with `Location:` headers).

Comment: @TokenMacGuy: I see what you mean, although my experience and intuition tells me that this is going to make life more difficult for both the developer and the client. For example, consider an array-style query parameter like `/links/?userids=1,2,3,4,5&categoryids=6,7,8,9,10` - having actual URIs in there quickly becomes unmanageable and may actually go over the [maximum length of a URL](http://stackoverflow.com/q/417142/38360). And IMO you're substituting one problem for another; instead of having to know what a "userid" means, the client must know the full user URI (which might change).

Comment: @waxwing : This comment is 3 years after the post. Anyways, don't you think there would be redundancy if we have the same representation of two resources i.e 1. api/v1//links  and 2. api/v1/user/1234/links ? How do you manage the redundancy.

Answer (score 3):

So my concern is:
/users/:userid/links returns "links", BUT if the user_id is not identified, this should return a 404.

However

/links?userid=:userid would potentially return an empty list (essentially a 200) which is actually probably a bug. And quite possible.

Although both work, the nesting gives you additional functionality you can later draw on.